# how to create dependent drop down list in YII? What is missing in Controller?

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii, frameworks

How To get Area DropDown/Select-Option by changing the City Option?

Find all Area List by City table primary key.

Condition is City(id) --> area(city_id) then I show that.

Now it's Show only **Null** when I change city option.

View:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'city'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'city', CHtml::listData(City::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'city'), 
        array(
            'prompt'=>'select',
            'ajax' => array(
                'type' => 'POST', //My method type
                'dataType' => 'JSON', 
                'url' => CController::createUrl('users/dynamiccities'), //This is my request/ajax URL
                'data'=>array(
                    'city'=>'js:this.value',
                ),
                'success'=>'js:function(data){
                    $("#Users_area").html(data.areaList);
                }' //The functionaliy after success
            )
        ));
     ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'city'); ?>
</div>

<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'area', array(), array('prompt'=>'select')); ?>
```

Controller:

```
public function actionDynamiccities(){
    $cityId = $_POST['city'];
    $areaList = '';

    if ($cityId != '') {
        $areaList = CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => ''), CHtml::encode("NULL"), true);    
    } else {
        $condition="city_id=".cityId;
        $data = Area::model()->findAll(array('condition'=>$condition), 'id');
        if($data){
            $areaList = CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => ""), "Select", true);
            foreach ($data as $d) {
                $areaList .= CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => $d->id), CHtml::encode($d->area), true);
            }
        }else {
            $areaList = CHtml::tag('option', array('value' => ''), CHtml::encode("NULL"), true);
        }
    }
    echo CJSON::encode(array(
        'areaList' => $areaList,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Is the ajax call made successfully? What is returned from the call - check the console for it?

Comment: Yes console post parameters pass city=1

Comment: But what is returned? Also the condition checked is `if ($cityId != '') { ...` - which means when `1` is passed, the `if` part is executed and not the `else` part.

Comment: {"areaList":"<option value=\"\">NULL<\/option>"}

Comment: Check the above comment. You need `if ($cityId == '') {...`

Comment: Thank Your so much ... now works.. You are Right. but my another mistake is $condition="city_id=".cityId; Now all right $condition="city_id=".$cityId;

Comment: this may help you http://codingbin.com/dependent-drop-down-lists-in-yii/